# Function not executing (Part of a logical statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When running the piece of code described below I get an interesting python behavior.

Apparently the python interpreter does some kind of optimization and does not run the function since the logical statement output is already known (False and True will still be equal false).

```
def some_func(x):
    print(x)
    return False

flag = True
for x in range(5):
    flag = flag and some_func(x)
```

output :

```
0
```

expected output :

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The obvious solution would be :

```
flag = true
for x in range(5):
    temp_flag = some_func(x)
    flag = flag and temp_flag
```

But I was wondering if there was some way to control the interpreters optimization (Or is this and IDE configuration)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) meaning that in the expression

```
flag and some_func()
```

`some_func()` will never be executed if `flag` is False, as the result of `some_func()` is not going to change the result (`False and x` is always False regardless of the values of x).

**Edit**: if you reverse the order:

```
flag = some_func() and flag
```

the logic will not change (`and` is commutative), but now `some_func()` will always execute.

**Edit 2:** if you have more than two arguments, this simple trick will not work. Consider this example:

```
>>> def f(name):
...     print(name)
...     return False
...
>>> f('A') and f('B') and f('C')
A
False
```

as you see, the execution will stop at `f('A')`.

In this case you can use `all()` in place of `and` to have all arguments evaluated:

```
>>> all([f('A'), f('B'), f('C')])
A
B
C
False
```

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to cancel it (I did write why it happened in the question).

Comment: Nice and elegant fix!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same without explicit loops:

```
results = [some_func(x) for x in range(5)]  # Collect a list of results.
flag = all(results)  # True if every value in `results` is True.
```